# PHP, adding to a database

Tags: php

When filling in the fields in the browser and presing add product it returns
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
instead of adding it to the database.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
$shipping = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shipping']);
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE name='$name'");
$productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productMatch > 0){
    echo'sorry name of film is already in database';
    exit();
}
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name,price,shipping,quantity,description,keywords,category)VALUES
('$name','$price','$shipping','$quantity','$description','$keywords','$category',now)") or die(mysql_error());
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$newname = "$id.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "./images/$newname");
}
?>
<?php

$product_list = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))   {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $catagory = $row["catagory"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $product_list .="";
    }
    }
    else {
    $product_list = "You have no products";
    }

?>
<?php echo $product_list; ?>

 <here is a form that contains all required data    

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php' ; ?>
```

any ideas cheers
this is to be used so we can add products to the database as an admin

Comment: They gave you the correct answer. By the way, you should think about using PDO or Mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is very clear in it self `Column count doesn't match value count`.
In your query values contains `now` at the end while you forget to mention the repective column for it.

Your columns:

```
name,price,shipping,quantity,description,keywords,category
```

While values:

```
'$name','$price','$shipping','$quantity','$description','$keywords','$category',now
```

**NOTE:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with this query, I think you missed a field

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (name,price,shipping,quantity,description,keywords,category)VALUES
('$name','$price','$shipping','$quantity','$description','$keywords','$category',now)") or die(mysql_error());
```

There are 7 fields here

```
name,price,shipping,quantity,description,keywords,category
```

But here there are 8 values,

```
'$name','$price','$shipping','$quantity','$description','$keywords','$category',now
```

So find out the field name for `now` value and that will fix the problem.

**NOTE:**

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.